What are these things in the wall of the spare room?
I am thinking about making this small room into a guest room (maybe a window in the door or the wall, adding a bed, etc).
There are some knobs and pipes in one of the walls (2nd pic below) that I don't know what they are - can these be removed without any issues?



what is the purpose of the first picture?

turn the two knobs

Where does the door with the double lock go?

@jay613 it goes outside (side door). Nobody ever uses it. Was thinking it wouldn't be too expensive to have a window added in that door to bring in some natural light. Or make it a wall with a window for continuity?

@Ecnerwal That door leads outside actually. But I was going to cover it up with the bed. But I'm confused by your comment. I'm not renting out the house or anything so I'm free to have guests sleep wherever I want, correct?

@jsotola the first image shows the pipe plug with the square drive on the end, to the right-hand side of image.    Both images show the same cardboard box titled "M..."

This is not a "rental" thing. It's a life safety thing, and ALL "sleeping" rooms need direct access to the outside, barring a few specific exceptions. So keep the door to the outside functional and that's good to go. The size of the drain cleanout suggests strongly that it serves considerably more than the laundry hookup.

Egress matters, but it isn’t clear whether there’s a window out of the picture frame. If that is literally the only way outside, it would be a grave error to wall it or put a non compliant window in.

The black pipe looks like a drain cleanout. The white pipe looks like a drain for a washing machine and the two valves with the blue handles look like hot and cold water valves for a washer although they are very low. You probably want to keep them. You can't just remove them without doing some extensive work.

So is it possible to make this into a (small) guest room still? Any ideas on how to do it?

@sg3333 Any ideas on how to do it? ... yes ... remove the junk and put in furniture ... it's a no-brainer

@sg3333  I'd cut the drain pipe down to about three inches from the elbow and remove the blue handles from the faucets. Then plan your room. Most furniture could be pushes up pretty close to these fittings and dressers could have the back cut out .

I'd be tempted to just hide them behind furniture and forget them until I needed an upstairs laundry room. Or make the room serve both functions; I've slept in the sofa in a friend's laundry room many times.

@keshlam   LOL  I've slept on the floor in a friend's laundry room many times...

Obvious dryer vent in top corner of the room definitely supports that theory.

No one seems to have mentioned that the white drain line needs to be capped, whether you cut it shorter or not. In the event of a plugged up drain farther down the line, you might have water coming out of it, flooding the room.

Here's my plan for you.
You have an exit door right there in the room, that's great.  Don't have to spend money on new emergency exits.   I'll assume that's an outside wall then, and it's not entirely underground, so you can add a window to the wall on either side of the door for natural light and fresh air.  Don't block the door with furniture.
Repurpose the laundry hookup to provide a small vanity table with a wash basin in the guest room.  Nice touch!  The black cleanout can be hidden by the same cabinet but make it accessible through a cupboard door.  You won't have to access it often, hopefully never, but you don't want a blocked drain to require destroying your vanity.
Perhaps the room is too small for a bed and a vanity?  Then the cold/hot/drain can probably be cut and capped on the opposite side of the wall, or perhaps inside it with minor drywall repair after, and the cleanout will be behind the bed.
Change the light fixture to something with less prison vibe.

This was exactly what I was looking for - thank you! Nobody else explained that the cold/hot/drain could be cut on the opposite side of the wall.

Probably.  It's a guess.  A photo of what's on the other side of the wall would help.  You must have looked by now ... ?!?!  Do you see those pipes there?

is a washing machine drain suitable for a basin? (I assume you'll have to install a siphon, but the existing drain is just a straight line of pvc, no?)

@njzk2 it would probably need some modification.  It might not have a trap or  it may be too low.   It may not be properly vented.  We can't assume too much from the one picture.

It's (not surprisingly) a plumbing code violation to block access to or conceal in an inacessible manner  a cleanout, even.

I'm guessing there was a deep sink in there once upon a time.  I've never seen a washing machine hookup that wasn't in the wall to give you the required air gap.
That said, if you want to get rid of them, all the pipes except the cleanout could be capped in the wall with minor sheetrock repair required afterward.  You could probably rotate the cleanout and put it behind an access panel but that seems like a lot of work for something you could just hide.
A door with a window works.  If you replace the door with a window it must meet egress standards.

Looks like hot and cold water supply, and drain line for a washing machine.

The only washing machine in the house is upstairs. Is this drain line doing anything for this or is it just in case we wanted another washing machine down there? Can all of these be removed?

The big black cleanout cannot be removed, and must remain accessible.

Obviously I’m late but good news and bad news. The good news is the room is supplied with water and a drain. I’m assuming there must be another laundry room and this was included for convenience and there is a very good chance it located above or below the main laundry room. The big white pipe is your ventilation for your dryer. You know the water spouts and the other is the drain. Just keep in mind that if the main laundry room is directly above or below it probably uses them for the same purpose(that would be the bad news).I’ve never seen a house with 2 interior laundry rooms. Whatever you decide to do make sure not to impede the functionality of infrastructure and negativity effect your main laundry ,bath rooms or kitchen . Any room using water,vent or drain. A window, in that case , could be an issue.
Still, you can hide everything exposed within the wall assuming you have the skill and patience. Keep in mind that depending on where you live permits might be required. If so and you don’t get them they can be petty. I’ve seen a situation of work done without a permit because the man was qualified and it was his house but ended up getting caught when he sold it as it didn’t match the plans the county had on file .Just fyi.
